# Change/add dimensions to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

here is the code I am referring to:

```
k = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
l = np.array([10,20])
outer = np.outer(l,k)
m = np.random.normal(0, .1, l.shape)
```

Outer has the shape (2,6) with the results of:

```
[[ 10  20  30  40  50  60]
 [ 20  40  60  80 100 120]]
```

I would like m to have the same dimensions. For exmaple, m is equal to:

```
[-0.14893783 -0.05070178]
```

I would like it have the same dimensions as outer like so:

```
[[ -0.14893783  -0.14893783  -0.14893783  -0.14893783  -0.14893783  -0.14893783]
 [ -0.05070178  -0.05070178  -0.05070178  -0.05070178 -0.05070178 -0.05070178]]
```

At the end I want to be able to add the values of m to every component of the outer matrix and they need to have the same dimensions. How can I do this with numpy?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to explicitly reshape. Numpy's broadcasting takes care of that automatically

```
m.reshape(-1, 1) + outer
```

Further details on how broadcasting works can be found [in the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)